# Get Powershell top-level script location?

Tags: powershell

$PSScriptRoot and $PSCommandPath are very useful in locating script files that are consumed by other scripts. Is there an easy, reliable way of getting the top-level script file that was actually executed? My users are right-clicking .ps1 files to execute them from File Explorer.

Example:

```
C:\Powershell\a.ps1
C:\Powershell\lib\b.ps1
```

I need a command that I can use from b.ps1 that preferably returns `C:\Powershell\a.ps1`, or at least `C:\Powershell`. `$PSScriptRoot`, `$PSCommandPath`, and `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` all return `C:\Powershell\lib\b.ps1`, though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
get-variable psscriptroot -scope ((get-pscallstack).count - 2)
```

That should get you the scriptroot in the fist child scope of the global scope, which would be the script scope of the initial script invocation.

Comment: Nice...I'm curious if this can be elegantly extended to accommodate N frames on the call stack.

Comment: It already does. No matter how far down the call stack you go, it will always reach back to the first child of the global scope and read the value of $PSScriptRoot from there.

Answer (score 0):

Inside b.ps1, use the cmdlet:

```
Get-Location
```

This will return the parent path that you expect.

**Why This Works:**
This works because you will navigate to the directory C:\Powershell\ and execute the script a.ps1 from there. When you execute `. .\lib\b.ps1` you haven't left that execution location, so it will return exactly what you want.

**Note:** Note that this only works if you first navigate to the directory first, or for scheduled tasks you specify a "Start in" directory. So if you are in a different directory and execute your first script like this: C:\Powershell\a.ps1 it will return your other directory.

If you are really keen, more info on encapsulation is here: [Further Down the Rabbit Hole PowerShell Modules and Encapsulation](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/further-down-the-rabbit-hole-powershell-modules-and-encapsulation/)

Comment: Oh, sorry--I should have specified that a.ps1 refers to b.ps1 using its own directory from $PSCommandPath, rather than navigating to it.